# subset of list of vector with grep?

Tags: r, string, lapply, grepl

I have a list of vector and I want to create a new list containing any value containing the letter 'a' but keep in internal structure.

```
l = list ( g1 = c('a','b','ca') , 
            g2 = c('a','b') )
lapply(l, function(x)  grep('a',x)  )
```

lapply on provides the index number but what I want it to return are the values. 
The end result should be a list with vector g1 containing a and ca whilst g2 with just a.

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `value = TRUE`.

```
lapply(l, function(x)  grep('a', x, value = TRUE))
# $g1
# [1] "a"  "ca"
# 
# $g2
# [1] "a"
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can do:

```
lapply(l, function(x)  x[grepl("a", x)])

$g1
[1] "a"  "ca"

$g2
[1] "a"
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to try with `tidyverse` here are couple of approaches.

```
library(tidyverse)
map(l, ~grep('a', .x, value=T))
map(l, ~str_subset(.x, 'a')) # str_subset from stringr package is a wrapper for grep shown above.
```